# load a 3d model and face detection in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, 3d, augmented-reality

I have been following this tutorial http://www.trappers.tk/site/2012/05/02/face-detection-with-core-image-on-live-video/ for adding an image to live video at the face position, however, now I would like to load a 3d object instead of an image, can you give me some hints about it? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NinevehGL view , refer [this link](http://nineveh.gl/)
 it loads 3D Model in a view

Comment: Hi bhuXan, I found that all those tutorials are about displaying 3d in the whole view, am I able to do that on a specific position such as at the mouth of man.

Comment: when I used it, i was adding 3D model on a UIView and was adding that uiview where i wanted to show 3D model.

Comment: got it, I think I am able to do that. 3q

Comment: hi Xan, it seems that the phone cant display myface and display the 3d view at the same time...it crashes, is it because ninevehgl is also using nglcamera?

Comment: can you show me your sample project, it's exactly what i need. 3q

Comment: https://github.com/SpotMetrix/3DAR-Visualize/tree/master/Classes I had used these EggView classes directly in my project but I did not create any POC. sorry.